# How to create a Nuxt 3 plugin/composables for Frappe JS SDK

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, frappe

I have used frappe-js-sdk to create the following page in Nuxt 3.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ notes }}
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { FrappeApp } from "frappe-js-sdk"
const runTimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
const frappe = new FrappeApp(runTimeConfig.apiBase, {
  useToken: true,
  token: () => runTimeConfig.apiSecret,
  type: "token", 
});

const db = frappe.db(); 

const notes = await db.getDocList("Note", {
  fields: ["name", "content"]
});

</script>

<script>
definePageMeta({layout: "default"});
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine. But how do I convert this section to either a plugin or composable so that I do not have to repeat it on every component or page I create?

```
import { FrappeApp } from "frappe-js-sdk"
const runTimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
const frappe = new FrappeApp(runTimeConfig.apiBase, {
  useToken: true,
  token: () => runTimeConfig.apiSecret,
  type: "token",
});

const db = frappe.db();
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction.

Even though I am new to programming and JS, I have managed to make reusable composables. But unable to figure this out.

[Find the Frappe JS SDK documentation here.](https://frappe.io/blog/engineering/frappe-in-nodejs-apps-serverless-functions)